# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars keep arriving

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I keep facing this error, i had read some case that have the same error, and i tried to convert every list to a numpy array, but it is still not work.

What exactly does this error means?

> ```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-4-b5b54f6e1f9e> in <module>
>      69 
>      70     model = LogisticRegression(eta = 0.01, n_iterations = 1000, lamb = 100)
> ---> 71     model.fit(x_train, y_train)
>      72     ypre = model.predict(x_test)
>      73     print(ypre)
>
> <ipython-input-4-b5b54f6e1f9e> in fit(self, x, y)
>      29             t = (hx - y)
>      30 
> ---> 31             s = self.cal_s(t, x, row, column)
>      32             gradient_w = np.sum(s, 0) / row * self.eta
>      33             gradient_b = np.sum(t, 0) / row * self.eta
>
> <ipython-input-4-b5b54f6e1f9e> in cal_s(self, t, x, row, colum)
>      17         for i in range(0,row):
>      18             for j in range(0, colum):
> ---> 19                 s[i][j] = t[i] * x[i][j]
>      20         return s
>      21 
>
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
> ```

Where did I go wrong? How can I solve it?

The function is work before i import some csv file.(I used np.random.rand to general it before)

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

class LogisticRegression:
    def __init__(self, eta, n_iterations, lamb):
        self.w = np.zeros(30) #theta
        self.b = 0 #theta 0
        self.eta = eta #Learing rate
        self.n_iterations = n_iterations #times for iterations
        self.lamb = lamb #
        self.r = (1 - lamb * self.eta / np.size(self.w, 0))

    def logistic(self, x):
        return 1.0/(1 + np.exp(-x))

    def cal_s(self, t, x, row, colum):
        s = np.zeros([row, colum], dtype=float)
        for i in range(0,row):
            for j in range(0, colum):
                s[i][j] = t[i] * x[i][j]
        return s

    def fit(self, x, y):
        itr = 0
        row, column = np.shape(x)
        print('number of instance', row)
        while itr <= self.n_iterations:
            fx = np.dot(self.w, x.T)
            hx = self.logistic(fx)
            t = (hx - y)

            s = self.cal_s(t, x, row, column)
            gradient_w = np.sum(s, 0) / row * self.eta
            gradient_b = np.sum(t, 0) / row * self.eta
            self.w = self.w * self.r - gradient_w
            self.b -= gradient_b
            itr += 1

    def predict(self, x_test):
        ypre = np.dot(self.w, x_test.T) + self.b
        temp = ypre >= 0
        yp = temp.astype(int)
        return yp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import csv

    with open('X_train.csv', newline='') as xTrain:

        xtrain = csv.reader(xTrain, delimiter=',')
        x_train = list(xtrain)
        x_train = np.array(x_train)
        x_train = x_train.astype(np.float)

    with open('Y_train.csv', newline='') as yTrain:

        ytrain = csv.reader(yTrain, delimiter=',')
        y_train = list(ytrain)
        y_train = np.array(y_train)
        y_train = y_train.astype(np.float)

    with open('x_test.csv', newline='') as xTest:

        xtest = csv.reader(xTest, delimiter=',')
        x_test = list(xtest)
        x_test = np.array(x_test)
        x_test = x_test.astype(np.float)

    model = LogisticRegression(eta = 0.01, n_iterations = 1000, lamb = 100)
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    ypre = model.predict(x_test)
    print(ypre)
```

Comment: Can you check the types of variables involved in line19?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the preferred indexing for a 2d array is `s[i,j]`.

`s` is a 2d array.  It looks like `x` has the same shape; I can't say for sure but, I suspect `t` is also 2d.  Otherwise `t[i]` would be a scalar, and assignment would work.  The error tells us that `t[i]*x[i,j]` is a 'sequence', most likely an array.  But `s[i,j]` can only accept a scalar, a number.

```
   s = np.zeros([row, colum], dtype=float)
    for i in range(0,row):
        for j in range(0, colum):
            s[i, j] = t[i] * x[i, j]
    return s
```

depending on the shape of `t`, this assignment can probably be written as

```
   s = t * x          # or
   s = t[:,None] * x
```

But the title shows a different error, about an argument that's supposed to be a scalar, a single number.  Instead you are giving it an array with more than one element.  You don't show the traceback of that error.

When debugging `numpy` code, pay detailed attention to the `shape` (and type and dtype) of all arrays.  You should know what is expected at each point in your code, and be prepared to check that knowledge.  Guesses produce errors.

Comment: s = t  *  x is not working, because t is (500, 500) and x is (500, 30)
s = t[:,None] * x still not working, the shape of t becomes (500,1,500)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (500,1,500) (500,30)

Comment: Well duh!  How do you expect to multiply a (500,500) by a (500,30) and produce a (500,500) array?  You can't do that iteratively, and you can't do with whole-array broadcasting.  Like I wrote, you have to pay close attention to array shapes.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. I means t(500,500) is a unexpected outcome,  t should be (500,). To achieve this, i need to change the shape of y first. The original shape of y is (500,1), i used numpy.ravel to change it to (500,). It should works now. But i facing another error of overflow: D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:13: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  del sys.path[0]